# Refresh gridview after change in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview, that shows record according to the selected value in the dropdownlist.
This works, on pageload the gridview only contains the records that it should contain.
But after choosing a different option in the dropdownlist, the gridview does not change.
I've tried fixing it with this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

But that does not work. I believe it's a very small matter, but after googling it I can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're currently doing from the code you've posted but typically you'd need to -

- Get the value from the drop down
- Query your data using using the new value
- Bind the resulting data to your datasource

The code you've posted looks as if it's only doing a bind of the already existing data to the GridView

Comment: also: be sure you set the Autopostbak="True" on the dropdownlist.